# How to add onmessage handler for strophe muc plugin

Tags: handler, strophe, multiuserchat

How to add on-message handler for strophe MUC plugin.

Currently i added callback function for join action.

```
Gab.connection.muc.join(room_name+"@muc.162.242.222.249",  login_id, 
function(message){
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check message types in your general message handler:

```
connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null, null);
```

...

```
function onMessage(msg) {
  var to = msg.getAttribute('to');
  var from = msg.getAttribute('from');
  var type = msg.getAttribute('type');
  var elems = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');

  if (type == "chat" && elems.length > 0) {
    var body = elems[0];
    console.log('CHAT: I got a message from ' + from + ': ' + Strophe.getText(body));
  } else if (type == "groupchat" && elems.length > 0) {
    var body = elems[0];
    var room = Strophe.unescapeNode(Strophe.getNodeFromJid(from));
    var nick = Strophe.getResourceFromJid(from);
    console.log('GROUP CHAT: I got a message from ' + nick + ': ' + Strophe.getText(body) + ' in room: ' + room);
  }
  // we must return true to keep the handler alive.  
  // returning false would remove it after it finishes.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply ..  Now  incoming messages working after adding this line.   connection.addHandler(Gab.on_message,
            null, "message", "groupchat");

Comment: Now the Next thing i want is message history for a user(When user click on joined group)  . Currently i have the following code for handling archive .                                                                                                                                                                                                                     connection.mam.query(
            Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(Gab.connection.jid), {
        with : jid+"@muc.server",
        max: 50,
        before: '',
  
        onMessage: function (message) {